# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {seconds, nanoseconds}) firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I keep getting this nasty error:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {seconds, nanoseconds}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Here is my code:

```js
const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      db.collection("users")
        .doc(user)
        .collection("notifications")
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
          setNotifications(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()))
        );
    } else {
      console.log("No Notifications");
    }
  }, [user]);
```

I have no clue what is wrong with my code. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us the code where you do the rendering?

Comment: Please edit the question to provide enough information that anyone can use to reproduce the issue.  We can't see what's in your database, nor do we know what line of code is causing the error.